# Creating function from Matlab cftool fit?

Tags: matlab, function, curve-fitting, data-fitting

I fit some data with high order polynomials as such:

```
ft = fittype('poly9');
[f,gof] = fit(x,y,ft);
```

and then turn this into a function:

```
func = @(x) f.p1*x.^9 + f.p2*x.^8 + f.p3*x.^7 + f.p4*x.^6 + f.p5*x.^5 + f.p6*x.^4 + f.p7*x.^3 + f.p8*x.^2 + f.p9*x + f.p10;
```

I therefore write out the function by hand. The problem is, this is very prone to typos. Is there a way to create a function automatically from a fit?

Answer (score 2):

You don't need to write the function, you can simply use the object `f` from the output of `fit`:

```
y_model = f(x);
```

where `y_model` is the result of input `x`.

Comment: Wow, okay, I didn't expect it to be so simple. Thanks! Do you know if I can easily integrate the resulting expression?

Comment: Also, can this be made to work for cases where x is a vector?

Comment: 1. This already works with `x` being a vector, matrix or any other size. 2. you can calculate the integral numerically with `integrate(f,xmax,xmin)`, where `xmin` and `xmax` are scalars the define the lower and upper limit of the integral, respectively. read more [here](https://www.mathworks.com/help/curvefit/integrate.html)